# Run Java method from JavaScript on button click

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jira, velocity

I need a way to call a Java method from Javascript and pass user input variables into the method call. The issue seems to be that Javascript resolves/evaluates the Java method on the page load. I am working with a JIRA (Atlassian) plugin

NOTE: I will be getting the user input from a form but didn't think it necessary to include the code here.

```
<button class="aui-button" onclick="javaMethodInJavascript">Remove Indicator</button>
<script>
  function javaMethodInJavascript(){
      $javaMethod.methodToCall(userInputOne, userInputTwo);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: HTML is on the client-side and the java code would be on the server-side - consider to use jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the difference between Java and JavaScript. Java is a *server-side* language and is executed on a server, whereas JavaScript is executed on *client-side*.

To establish communication between them, you need to *post* data from the client to the server. You can easily do this if you use **AJAX**.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'servlet.url',
    data: 'data=' + variable1 + '&data2=' + variable2
});
```